# Como ordenar array randômico em PHP

Tags: php

Olá pessoal tou com uma dificuldade como faço para ordenar esse array com valores de sub arrays de forma que sempre que o script for chamado venha com valores diferentes de forma randômico?

Esse é o array normal:

```
$results = array (0 => array 1 => int 5, 1 => array 2 => int 3, 2 => array 8 => int 5);
```

Ex: Script Roda primeira vez venha

```
$results = array (1 => array 2 => int 3, 0 => array 1 => int 5, 2 => array 8 => int 5);
```

Ex: Script Roda segunda vez venha

```
$results = array (2 => array 8 => int 5, 1 => array 2 => int 3, 0 => array 1 => int 5);
```

E assim sucessivamente!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que essa pergunta é duplicata, como não achei na rede... 
Tu busca pela função [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shuffle.php)

```
$numbers = array(array(1),array(2),array(5),array(10),array(20),array(3),array(4),array(60));
var_dump($numbers);
echo "<br/>";
shuffle($numbers);
var_dump($numbers);
```

Comment: Isso mesmo cara certinho deu certo é isso mesmo muito obrigado!